# Docker and Django. django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I can't find solution, please help!

I have **Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install Django \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && pip install jinja2 \
    && pip install Pillow

COPY . /app/
```

And **docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=folivora
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  site:
    image: folivora:latest
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

And **settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'folivora',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

And **ERROR** when run "docker-compose up"

```
site_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
site_1  |   Is the server running on host "db" (192.168.224.2) and accepting
site_1  |   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When I edit docker-compose.yaml, change string command to:

```
command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

all is fine. So, migration line broke my code, but i don't know why.

I try to create empty django project to check the same config. On first "docker-compose up", all started and working fine, but from second start, all is broke again with the same error. Over time this problem gone from test project, I dont know why, maby cache or something...

**New info**

1. Run `docker-compose up` with command `command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"` in docer-compose.yaml and catch error.
2. Then Ctrl+C (exit from docker compose "shell") but don't do `docker-compose down`, because this command delete created container.
3. Run `docker-compose up` with command `command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"` in docer-compose.yaml and all is successfull started.

I think it is bad solution.

Comment: I think the problem is that your Django app starts calling migration commands before your database becomes actually running. Note that `depends_to` only manages order of creation of containers, not their readiness. Can you try `wait-for-it db:5432` before migrations?

Answer (score 1):

According to your edit, you don't have any networking issues.

The problem is that your Django app starts calling migration commands before your database becomes actually running (you can check that in postgres logs). Also note that `depends_to` only manages order of creation of containers, not their readiness.

You can use `wait-for-it` to wait until your postgres port is available. So, your `command` would be:

```sh
bash -c "wait-for-it db:5432 -- python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

If your image doesn't have this package installed, add `apt install wait-for-it` to your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks, it is help. But in Dockerfile I add not `RUN apt install wait-for-it` but `RUN apt-get -q update && apt install wait-for-it`

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db:5432'